# heightReference property for CZML

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs, czml

Can the `heightReference` property be used in CZML for clamping polygon to ground?

Line no 56 below and [here](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/master/Apps/Sandcastle/gallery/Ground%20Clamping.html) uses it for entities in Cesium.

```
heightReference : Cesium.HeightReference.CLAMP_TO_GROUND
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's just:

```
    "heightReference" : "CLAMP_TO_GROUND"
```

The property is available on `point`, `billboard`, and `label` graphics in CZML.  If you're using multiples of those on the same entity, you should set this value for each.

Comment: Thanks @emackey, but polygon with height or extrudedHeight don't get clamped to terrain.